# Why is the Vector menu missing upon installation of QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-processing

Why is the Vector menu missing upon installation of QGIS 3.0?

Others mentioned that some of the tools were missing from the menu when they installed a previous version, but in my case the entire Vector menu is missing including all of the geoprocessing tools I need.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm having this error after I installed 3.6 on my Mac and this disables my Vector application: > Couldn't load plugin 'processing' > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo' Traceback (most recent
> call last): File
> "/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
> line 309, in loadPlugin
> __import__(packageName) File "/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
> line 672, in _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) File
> "/Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins

Answer (score 9):

Go to the menu *Plugins - Manage and Installed Plugins*. Make sure the plugin **Processing** is enabled.

Comment: I am having the same problem and Processing is installed. It won't allow me to edit it because it says it is a core plugin

Comment: @Tim Forssman As a core plugin, you can't uninstall it, but you might be able to enable/disable it. Enable it and restart qgis